# Ajax Tool kit error in page when use Script Manager

Tags: asp.net

in status bar in internet explorer say "Done, but with errors in page"

i place Script Manager in form but error and cant use update panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable Script Manager compression and see if it works.

*How to do? Easy, just edit your web.config:

```
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
    <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression=“false” enableCaching=“true”/>
  </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Comment: and i cant used updatepanel i think my computer dont have js file